# QuickSight and Ruby integration, unable to display the graph inside the RoR application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

I am building a QuickSight dashboard, which can be displayed within my RoR application. Has anyone done some work on this? I could find the following articles about it, but not much latest context on how to actually make it work.

```
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/index.html?id=docs_gateway
https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-quicksight-embedding-sample
https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/aws-sdk-quicksight/frames
https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/aws-sdk-quicksight/Aws/QuickSight/Client
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/QuickSight/Client.html
https://bestgems.org/gems/aws-sdk-quicksight
https://medium.com/@channaly/quicksighthow-to-embed-amazon-quick-sight-to-your-ruby-on-rails-application-26b1de5c7baf
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/tree/master/gems/aws-sdk-quicksight
```

When I embed the code and try to use it on localhost, it gives me an error (HTTPS and LocalHost are not recognized by AWS QuickSight), which I worked around by making an entry in the /etc/hosts.

For the HTTPS issue, used NGNIX to create an SSL based local server.

So, just wish to check if anyone has worked on embedding QuickSight with Ruby/Rails code and can provide pointers on the capabilities and what needs to be done.

Comment: One thing to note about embedding is that you have to trust embedded domains in QuickSight's admin configuration. I'm not really sure how that works for localhost, to be honest, it may not.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few prerequisites to being able to embed:

- Be subscribed to the enterprise edition of QuickSight
- Trust embedded domains, in admin settings, at https://us-east-1.quicksight.aws.amazon.com/sn/admin#embedding (replace us-east-1 with your region if different)

To get embedding to work for localhost, I've had success adding `https://127.0.0.1:{SERVICE_PORT}` to the list of allowed domains, replacing `{SERVICE_PORT}` with the port your Rails service is running on. Asterisks/pattern matching don't work, so it seems for now at least you'll have to commit to a specific port (or a few) for your service to run on when developing locally.

More detail here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/approve-domain-for-dashboard-embedding.html.